# How to use C# 6 syntax in msbuild inline tasks?

Tags: c#, msbuild, task

Please, consider the following inline task:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="HelloWorld" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
<Task>
  <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Framework" />
  <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Utilities" />
  <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
    <![CDATA[Console.WriteLine($"Hello {0+1}");]]>
  </Code>
</Task>
</UsingTask>
```

It does not compile - `error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'`

I would like to use C# 6 syntax here. How do I enable it?

Comment: Good question, not sure how this works. I assumed it used the same compiler as your main code but I guess that's not the case. Maybe you can get better results using [`RoslynCodeTaskFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-roslyncodetaskfactory)?

Comment: 15.8 will include `RoslynCodeTaskFactory` in-box, until then there's the OOB version [on GitHub](https://github.com/jeffkl/RoslynCodeTaskFactory)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `CodeTaskFactory` uses CodeDom to compile C# code which doesn't implement newer C# versions.

MSBuild 15.8 (In preview at time of writing) there is a new `RoslynCodeTaskFactory` that uses the roslyn compiler to compile your code which allows you to use the current C# version that's contained in the distribution of MSBuild / Visual Studio:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build">
  <UsingTask TaskName="HelloWorld" TaskFactory="RoslynCodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
    <Task>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[Console.WriteLine($"Hello {0+1}");]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <HelloWorld />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use it with msbuild 14?

Comment: No, it is in the 15.8 version of msbuild / visual studio 2017