How to use .NET 6 functions in msbuild inline tasks?
I have Visual Studio 2022, and I have .NET 9 installed.
During build (before the build starts, actually), I need to create a symbolic link, and I need to do so in a cross-platform way, because I am on Windows, but github actions runs on ubuntu.
So, I created an "Inline Task", a.k.a. "UsingTask" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/usingtask-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022) from which I want to invoke System.IO.File.CreateSymbolicLink(). (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createsymboliclink?view=net-6.0)
Here is my code:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    ...
    <UsingTask TaskName="CreateFileSymbolicLink" 
            TaskFactory="RoslynCodeTaskFactory" 
            AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll" >
        <ParameterGroup>
            <path ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
            <pathToTarget ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
        </ParameterGroup>
        <Task>
            <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
                //System.Console.WriteLine( $"x" );
                System.IO.File.CreateSymbolicLink( path, pathToTarget );
            </Code>
        </Task>
    </UsingTask>

It fails with

error CS0117: 'File' does not contain a definition for 'CreateSymbolicLink'.

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51194833/773113 (from 2018) and I tried using the string interpolation syntax, and that one works, but not the CreateSymbolicLink() method.
How can I get this to work, or otherwise achieve my original goal, which was to create a symbolic link to a file in a cross-platform way before build begins?

I can think of a couple of variants that might work, but this is just off the top of my head and none are actually tested. (1) Run a powershell script instead. Powershell is also available in linux. (2) Use a Windows-runner instead of ubuntu-latest (i.e. windows-latest).

It seems that the RoslynCodeTaskFactory is not finding the .Net 9 SDK. How are you building? Are you using the dotnet tool and does dotnet --info indicate .Net 9?

If you add <Using Namespace="System.IO"/> in your Task element, will the error persist? Besides, i noticed File.CreateSymbolicLink(String, String) Method is apply to .NET 6,7,8,9. Please check if your framework meet this requirement.

@JonathanDodds behavior is same when building either from within Visual Studio or from the command-line with dotnet build -verbosity:detailed.   The command dotnet --info lists 9.0.101 under ".NET SDKs Installed".  (It is the only dotnet sdk installed.)

@DouXu-MSFT As per your suggestion, I tried adding <Using Namespace="System.IO"/>, it did not make any difference, as expected.  I stated I have dotnet 9 installed.  My project is targeting dotnet 8, if that matters.  The statement System.IO.File.CreateSymbolicLink( "", "" ); compiles just fine in a .cs file.

Also, in the inline task, if I precede the problematic statement with string s = $"x"; and with System.IO.File.Delete( "" );, they are both accepted: the error is still issued on the same problematic statement, not on the preceding ones.

@JonathanDodds one strange thing is that when building from within Visual Studio,  MSBuildToolsPath is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64 and  RoslynTargetsPath is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn, whereas when building with dotnet build MSBuildToolsPath is C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\9.0.101 and RoslynTargetsPath is C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\9.0.101\Roslyn. And yet both methods give the same error.

Please note that RoslynCodeTaskFactory tasks target .NET Standard, so you can't use CreateSymbolicLink in tasks. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-roslyncodetaskfactory?view=vs-2022

So, I had to abandon the idea of doing it in a cross-platform way.
This is what I ended up doing:
<UsingTask TaskName="CreateFileSymbolicLink" TaskFactory="RoslynCodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll" >
    <ParameterGroup>
        <path ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
        <targetPath ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
        <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
            //PEARL: We cannot simply use System.IO.File.CreateSymbolicLink() here, because RoslynCodeTaskFactory
            //       tasks target .NET Standard. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/79308054/773113

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport( "Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode )]
            [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs( System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.I1 )]
            static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink( string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, uint dwFlags );

            System.IO.File.Delete( path );

            //PEARL: This will fail with 0x80004005 ("Unspecified error") unless we use the
            //       SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_ALLOW_UNPRIVILEGED_CREATE magical incantation.
            //PEARL: This requires that we are either running privileged, or Windows "Developer Mode" is enabled.
            if( !CreateSymbolicLink( path, targetPath, /* File + SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_ALLOW_UNPRIVILEGED_CREATE */ 0x2 ) )
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception( System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), $"Failed to create symbolic link {path} {targetPath}" );
        </Code>
    </Task>
</UsingTask>

Invoke as follows:
<Target Name="MyTarget" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" >
    <ItemGroup>
        <CreateFileSymbolicLink path="<source-file>" targetPath="<target-file>" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>


Actually, SCRATCH ALL OF THE ABOVE, here is what I ACTUALLY ended up doing:
<Target Name="MyTarget" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
        <FilesToCopy Include="source-file-1" />
        <FilesToCopy Include="source-file-2" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="<destination-directory>"
                SkipUnchangedFiles="True" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="True"
                UseSymboliclinksIfPossible="True" />
</Target>

